# Geolocation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, geolocation

I have the following problem, the geolocation doesn't work. I use eclipse with phonegap libraries and adt plugin. The code of my project is in html and jquery.
The script that i use is this:

```
function initialize() {

    var locations = [
        ['Hougang', 1.37265, 103.893658],
        ['Punggol', 1.400617, 103.907833],
        ['MacRitchie Reservoir', 1.346002, 103.825436],
        ['Bishan', 1.352051, 103.849125],
        ['Sentosa', 1.251226, 103.830757]
        ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.37265, 103.893658),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));
    }

    // Check if user support geo-location
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
            var geolocpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: geolocpoint,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            // Place a marker
            var geolocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: geolocpoint,
                map: map,
                title: 'Your geolocation',
                icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
            });
        });
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I do not understand where can be the error.

Comment: Try with Chrome console to see if there is any error.

Comment: I had already thought of it but unfortunately the computer I'm using is not working Chrome. Could you please check if you see errors? Thanks

Comment: Did you managed the map element height in style markup? i.e  "html, body, #map { margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%; }". Otherwise map will be there working, but not shown.

Comment: Your code is working well in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xLTPH/ must be some other thing breaking it.

Comment: Well, there is also IE Developer Tools, in case it helps.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359

Comment: Yes it work but doesn't show my position when I run it.

Comment: thanks Oscar, I check it in IE developer and there are not errors. I don't know why not show my current position in the map!